# Need help writing a SQL query to combine some fields

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am currently trying to get my head around a sql script to export some data, I have a table in a database that looks something like this:

```
Part_No       Op_No       Tool_No
110301         10          PPG220
110301         10          PPG221
110301         10          PPG222
110301         20          PPG220
110301         20          PPG221
1103012        10          PPG220
1103012        10          PPG224
1103012        10          PPG228
```

What I would like to do is export each part number so it looks more like this:

```
Part_No       Op_No       Tool_No
110301         10          PPG220,PPG221,PG222
110301         20          PPG220,PPG221
1103012        10          PPG220,PPG224,PPG228
```

Combining each of the Tools into one line based on the Part and Op number.

Help?

Cheers..

(I am not sure how to format the columns as this is my first post on this site)

Comment: it's always better to be as specific as possible. STRING_AGG was introduced in SQL Server 2017, but you have alternatives for earlier versions as well.

Answer (score 2):

Use `string_agg()`:

```
select part_no, op_no,
       string_agg(tool_no, ',') within group (order by tool_no)
from t
group by part_no, op_no;
```